# Facebook change image in page tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to change a facebook page tab image programatically. The idea is when my app will finish the instalation process, it will be change the image of the tab where it place it. After finish the process and give permissions to the app, The response of fb is "unautorized"

```
{"error":{"message":"(#300) Edit failure","type":"OAuthException","code":300}}
```

I searched about this error, the most close aproach was: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/255313014574414/.
I tried the same CURL example described in the error and have the same response.

The strange thing is, when i tried change the image inside fb, it fails too. I think the problem is when the app ask permissions to install in the user page, and don't have enough permits.

But i don't know hot i chage the permit to authorize chage the image of the pagetab.

Comment: I'm also getting this, so I suppose it is FB API burp. Here it is an open issue in their bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/255313014574414/

Comment: I get this error if the image is not the EXACT right size (111px x 74px). Facebook used to resize the image and not give an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fbparams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
          string path = @"c:\test.jpg";
          FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      var picture = new FacebookMediaObject
                {
                        //Tell facebook that we are sending image
                    ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                    //Give name to the image
                    FileName = "test"
                };
                //Create a new byteArray with right length
                var img = tabImageInfo.Media;
                //Convert the image content into bytearray
               fs.Read(img, 0, img.Length);`enter code here`
                 //Close the stream
               fs.Close();
                //Put the bytearray into Picture
                picture.SetValue(img);
                //Add the image into parameters
                fbparams.Add("custom_image", picture);
        fb.Post(tab.id, fbparams);
```

Comment: Try the above code. it should work and make sure the image is of 111 * 74