# How to edit page tab image? OAuthException: (#300)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use facebook php sdk and try to change tab image like this:

```
$facebook = new \Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '{APP_ID}',
    'secret' => '{APP_SECRET}',
    'fileUpload' => true,
 ));

$facebook->api('PAGE_ID/tabs/app_{APP_ID}', 'POST', array(
    'custom_image' => '@path/to/image.png',
    'access_token' => {PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN} 
));
```

But it doesn't works. Throws

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#300) Edit failure thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1294
```

What does that mean?

Same occurs if I try to edit source url:

```
...'custom_image_url' => '{facebook_image_url_here}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me so far, the docs under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/#updatepost have the same request structure.

Have you checked [Facebook change image in page tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670873/facebook-chage-image-in-page-tab)? Other users are reporting that the image needs to be 111px x 74px to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you! I used a picture with a suggested sizes and it worked well. Strange that this is not mentioned in the documentation.